# Redirect windows console output from another process to file

Tags: windows, debugging, cmd, printf, windows-console

I have a DLL which does as plugin into the TS3 client.
The problem is, the plugin provokes a crash that I cannot seem to find in my code directly.

So my idea is to set the Console Output of the console windows in the background (-console option) to a file, because when the program crashes there is no way I can read the console output as the console disappears immediately.

**Is there a way to set the output of a crashing console to a file?**

Because so far, when using the stdout operator (*ts3client_win64 -console > output.txt*) it does not write anything to the file. (I assume it cannot close the file handle and loses all its data?) But I want to **keep the console output when the crash occurs**.

It also has to be said that I can not just run it with a batch file and a pause statement, because when starting the application **it opens its own console window** (**and thats the one of which I want the output**).

It is the type of crash one would get from failed (safe) string operations in C like strtok_s or strcpy_s.

Comment: Why can't you have your plugin spawn a new shell at startup, such as `_spawnlp(_P_NOWAIT, "cmd.exe", "cmd.exe", NULL)`? Or spawn any other console app that waits for input, or indefinitely. It just needs to keep the console referenced to prevent the window from being destroyed. Otherwise, why can't you run the process under a debugger such as windbg or cdb? You'll be able to do immediate postmortem analysis, such as `!analyze -v`.

Comment: Would the debugging work with DLLs inside an application too?
And wouldnt the window be destroyed when the main application crashes?
But technically a good idea, I will try that!

Comment: In Windows 7+, each console window is hosted by its own instance of conhost.exe. The host exits as soon as there are no attached clients and (in Windows 8+) no references to its files (e.g. input, output, currentin, currentout, etc), which have rundown protection.

Comment: As to debugging the modules (EXE, DLLs) of a process, the separation between modules is primarily with respect to runtime loading, linking, activation contexts, and entry points. Memory, object handles, threads, and the debug port are relative to the process, not individual modules.